# Mysql content that show '? ' symbol

Tags: mysql

I have database content display problem on my page it is displaying the `�` in place of html special chars such as `&`,`'`,`""`, and double space. I have exported the database from one server and imported it to another server.  I used the `str_replace` and `strip tags` to remove it but didn't work.  I have also checked the  collation on both database that is same in both database and `charset=utf-8` in meta tag on the page.  Please let me know how can I remove this symbol and display the spacial chars.

Thanks

Comment: What encoding is your database in? What encoding does your page use?

Comment: And your documents have the correct encoding?

Comment: I m using the character set 'utf8_general_ci' in database and in page character set is utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` after your connection. This sometimes happens when your connection has the wrong default character set defined by default.